# KeyboardAvoidingView not working with Expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I cannot seem to get the keyboard to push the content up in my React-Native Expo app. I am testing this from the expo App by publishing it from my development machine.

Try as I might, nothing seems to push the view up when the keyboard comes into focus, is there a specific order of components, or some property I am missing; I have included the versions, the render block and the style blocks I think which are relevant.

I am using the following versions (latest);

```
"expo": "^29.0.0",
"react": "16.3.1",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-29.0.0.tar.gz",
```

For the login page, the render code looks like the following;

```
 render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.flexContainer}>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        style={styles.flexContainer}
        behavior="padding"
      >
        <Image style={styles.image} source={require('../../assets/images/backgroundWelcome.png')} role="presentation" />
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={[styles.row, styles.border]}>
            <TextInput 
              placeholder='Email' 
              style={styles.input} 
              onChangeText={(input) => this.setState({email: input})} 
              value={this.state.email} 
            />
          </View>
          <View style={[styles.row, styles.border]}>
            <TextInput 
              placeholder='Password'
              style={styles.input}
              secureTextEntry={true}
              onChangeText={(input) => this.setState({password: input})}
              value={this.state.password} 
            />
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <StyledButton callback={this.handleLogin} title='Log In'/>
          </View>

        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }
```

These are the styles that are relevant;

```
  root: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  flexContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  container: {
    paddingHorizontal: 40,
    paddingBottom: 22,
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: -1
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
```

Comment: did you ever get this fixed? im running into an issue like this too.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52112707/keyboardavoidingview-works-on-expo-but-not-on-apk

Comment: I hope the below might shed some insight, if it does, please upvote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ultimately could not find a full solution to the above directly, but I did find a npm module called.

```
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';
```

I then nested this inside a `ScrollView` and included the `View` and `Form` inside it.

```
<ScrollView
<KeyboardAwareScrollView>
<View>
  <!-- stuff -->
<View
<KeyboardAwareScrollView>
<ScrollView>
```

The module can be found here;

[react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view)

*At the time of writing appears a very popular module with ~30k downloads a week. I have no affiliation to this module, but it works for me.*

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue adding flex: 1 to KeyboardAvoidingView fixed my problem:

```js
            <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{ flex: 1 }} behavior={"padding"} >

                <ScrollView >

                    <Card>

                        <CardItem header bordered>
                            <Text>Personal Information</Text>
                        </CardItem>

                        <CardItem bordered>

                            <Body>

                                <Item floatingLabel style={styles.item}>
                                    <Label>Full Name</Label>
                                    <Input />
                                </Item>

                                <Item floatingLabel style={styles.item}>
                                    <Label>Headline</Label>
                                    <Input />
                                </Item>

                                <Item floatingLabel style={styles.item}>
                                    <Label>Location</Label>
                                    <Input />
                                </Item>

                                <Item floatingLabel style={styles.item}>
                                    <Label>Email</Label>
                                    <Input />
                                </Item>

                                <Item floatingLabel style={styles.item}>
                                    <Label>Phone Number</Label>
                                    <Input />
                                </Item>
                                <Item floatingLabel style={styles.item}>
                                    <Label>Phone Number</Label>
                                    <Input />
                                </Item>
                                <Item floatingLabel style={styles.item}>
                                    <Label>Phone Number</Label>
                                    <Input />
                                </Item>

                            </Body>
                            
                        </CardItem>

                    </Card>

                    <ListItem>

                        <Left>
                            <Text>Make my Profile Public</Text>
                        </Left>

                        <Right>
                            <Switch value={this.state.publicProfileRadioValue}
                                onValueChange={(value) => this.setState({ publicProfileRadioValue: value })}
                            />
                        </Right>
                        
                    </ListItem>

                </ScrollView>

            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Comment: when you look closely, you'll see @dhj already implement KeyboardAvoidingView as { flex: 1 }.

Comment: no actually, just overlook the all answer and just figured out you are same style with the code asked.

Answer (score 0):

I could achieve the right behavior with this implementation:

1. Removed KeyboardAvoidingView component.
2. Added this to the `app.json` file:

```
     "android": {
      "softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan"
    }
```

Hope it works for you guys as well!

Answer (score 0):

Add minHeight property to the root view style.

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView 
      behavior={Platform.OS == 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
      style={styles.container}> 
        {//content } 
</KeyboardAvoidingView>



minHeight: Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').height),
```

Do not forget to import Dimensions form react native

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
```

Answer (score -1):

for anyone else who ran into this when testing on Android, make sure the element you want to be keyboard avoided also has `flex: 1`.

this will not work:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior={Platform.OS == "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
      >
   <TextInput style={{ height: 300 }} />
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

this will:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior={Platform.OS == "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
      >
   <TextInput style={{ flex: 1 }} />
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

without flex 1, the target element will not resize its height accordingly to avoid the keyboard